# MALLET: How to implement crf based edit distance?

Tags: java, machine-learning, mallet, crf

I'm attempting to track down an edit distance algorithm that is supposedly implemented in [MALLET](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/).

I want to use the CRF edit distance algorithm as described [here](http://people.cs.umass.edu/%7Emccallum/papers/crfstredit-uai05.pdf) (by Andrew McCallum et al). The authors confirm its Mallet inclusion here in the FST class:

> The model has been implemented as part of the
> finite-state transducer classes in Mallet.

However, neither the [FST tutorial page](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/fst.php) - which shows an NER tagger - or the [test cases](https://github.com/mimno/Mallet/tree/master/src/cc/mallet/fst/tests) are of any help, at least that I can see.

**Questions**:

- *Where* can I find the implementation of the edit distance CRF algorithm in Mallet?
- *How* can I use it?